# Main Form got hang during long running process in different thread.

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using threading in my windows form application.

### Code

```
Thread sqlProcessThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doSqlWork));
sqlProcessThread.IsBackground = true;  
sqlProcessThread.Start();
```

When ever this thread is called from my form at that time the form got hang.
How can i solve this problem with out using background worker.

Comment: That on its own won't hang the main form. Something must be (possibly indirectly) causing it inside `doSqlWork()`

Comment: Yes this.Invoke causing this problem.But without using this it troughs error cross thread operation not valid.

Comment: How often do you perform `Invoke`? Aside from the already posted answer, perhaps you're simply trying to perform UI operations too often, or said operation itself is lengthy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use property InvokeRequired to check UI acess from different thread.

```
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.updateUI));
            return;
        }
```

More information: [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Invoke()` from a background thread, it will wait for the UI to respond before continuing.

It's possible for the UI to respond to the `Invoke()` call by waiting on something which requires the background thread to do further processing. If that happens, you get deadlock.

If you do *not* require a return value from the UI call, you can often fix this by using `BeginInvoke()` instead of `Invoke()`.

Calling `BeginInvoke()` will return immediately to the background thread that calls it, preventing the deadlock.

This has to be used with care.

Comment: BeginInvoke() works fine when i debug my project from visual studio.
But when i execute exe file again form got hanged during long running process.